# Can I install apps on Lion without using app store?

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

Is it true that I can only install app from app store in OS X Lion?

Can I not install app from any other source?

Comment: Unless this has been specifically answered by Apple in a public forum, I'd imagine anyone who knows the answer to this is under NDA and thus won't be able to talk about it here.

Comment: Despite being a good question - this is speculation about a pre-announced software.

Comment: There may be NDAs but they are leaky.  Cocoasodt, for example, just pointed out that the next release of PathFinder -  NOT in the app store - works fine on Lion. I don't think its speculative at all to talk about that.

Comment: Answers are getting upvotes but this  question gets downvote? Is this really such bad question that downvote is necessary? Strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not true - mean sure can install apps from dmg.

The Lion remain a full-blown OS, with all common functions, like Terminal.app, root access, Developer system, and so on. When here is **no way** block installing applications if you will have a root access, so Apple sure will NOT TRY do this.

The following is only my opinion:

On the other side - most of developers will sell their apps via AppStore (because it is easy), so here will be less "demo downloads" (what was possible activated by simple serial#). IMHO, over the time will be here more and more application in AppStore in two versions, like for example:

- SudokuLite.app (like current demo versions) - free,
- Sudoku.app (full paid version)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not true. Without breaking the NDA I can say, that many developers made their software Lion compatible and distribute it from their sites.